# How to fetch value of the Datasource in spring frarmework using JAVA code?

Tags: java, spring

I have spring application and using property file want to read the values from the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Here datasource is given as Id.

I want to read the values of the datasource property `jdbc.driverClassName` value using *java* code.

Scenario should be: 1st bean will be executed. It will load the data from the `jdbc.property` file. All the values in the datasource should be read from the *java* code.

How to read the values from the Java code for `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer(datasource)`?

Given the executed scenario below :

Create a properties file (database.properties), include your database details, put it into your project class path.

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkyongjava
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=password
```

---

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
    <property name="location">
        <value>database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="{jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="{jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="{jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

Please help me out using *java* code to read the data from the given datasource? 
Or any useful link from where i can find out the resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two simple options:

1. Get a reference to the application context (if you instantiated it yourself, that should be easy- if you initialized it using say `web.xml`, you might be able to retrieve it using `org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils`). Then obtain the bean using `BeanContext<T>.T getBean(String name, Class<T> requiredType)`, retrieve the properties using `DriverManagerDataSource`'s getters.
2. Inject the same values into one of your own beans; Spring will put the same values for you

Comment: Hi Thanks for fast reply. I understood the way you explain, but can you please help me out using JAVA source code. It will be convenient at my end to get the proper result using Java code. I want to execute the java code and based on it, want to write the values on the console for the (Driver,url,uname and password).